# How to create a progress bar?

Tags: programming, dynamic, monitoring

I would like to create a progress bar tool that allows me to see how my computations are going.

I found answers to this question on many sites, I even found a package for it ( http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~jeremy/mathematica/progress/#download ), but unfortunately, I have no knowledge whatsoever on programming and such, so I could not really understand the instructions for installing it properly (didn't know wether to use a notebook to create the package, go to the kernel, or something else?).

So I would really really appreciate if somebody could provide detailed step by step instructions for me to be able to get the progress bar going.

Comment: I use Windows 7 btw.

Comment: What I meant was if there was a way to get an add on for a permament progress bar for arbitrary computations.

Comment: Sorry you didn't understand my instructions. But note that I wrote that package for Mathematica 5.2. Mathematica 6 and later have built-in mechanisms (like ProgressIndicator, as pointed out by Brett) that are much better than, and don't have the overhead of, my package. I now use those; I don't use http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~jeremy/mathematica/progress/#download any more.

Comment: @EliyahUribe how could the kernel know when an arbitrary computation would finish? eg, consider this `While[r = RandomReal[]; r < .999999, 1]`; how long will it take? and there are simple computations which you really do need to carry out to find out how long they'll take

Comment: You can also monitor "estimated time remaining" till the end. Here is how: http://tiny.cc/c2v00w

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I'd build something using `Monitor` and `ProgressIndicator`.  For example:

```
Monitor[
 Table[Pause[0.1]; Prime[i], {i, 100}],
 Row[{ProgressIndicator[i, {1, 100}], i}, " "]
 ]
```

This shows a progress indicator while the calculation is underway

[image]

and then it disappears once the calculation has finished

[image]

---

If you look at Jeremy's file `progress.m` you linked to, you'll see that he defined functions like `ProgressTable` that are able to understand the iterator specifications.  This is a decent approach, and I'm now going to do something similar in writing a `ShowProgress` function that understands basic `Table` iterators and has a generic fallback.

```
(* ShowProgress needs to hold it's arguments, otherwise it 
   tries to show progress for something that's already 
   completely done.*)
SetAttributes[ShowProgress, HoldAll];

(* Basic table syntaxes.  Excludes {i, {i1, i2, ...}} and multi-iterator forms *)
ShowProgress[Table[e_, {i_, max_}]] := 
   ShowProgress[Table[e, {i, 1, max, 1}]]
ShowProgress[Table[e_, {i_, min_, max_}]] := 
   ShowProgress[Table[e, {i, min, max, 1}]]
ShowProgress[Table[e_, {i_, min_, max_, step_}]] := 
   Monitor[
      Table[e, {i, min, max, step}],
      Row[{ProgressIndicator[i, {min, max}], i}, " "]
      ]

(* Fall-back: shows an indeterminate progress bar and elapsed time, 
   updating a few times per second *)
ShowProgress[a_] := 
   With[{progressStartTime = AbsoluteTime[]},
      Monitor[
        a, 
        Dynamic[Refresh[
           Row[{
              ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[Clock[]], Indeterminate], 
              AbsoluteTime[] - progressStartTime
              }, " "], 
           UpdateInterval -> 0.25]]
        ]]
```

Here are some examples of `ShowProgress` in use:

[image]
[image]

---

I like this approach instead of the use of `Progress...` functions like in Jeremy's package because you don't need to change much of your code.  You could hook `ShowProgress` in via `$Pre` to get automatically applied to everything.  If you're willing to change code and use a special function when needed, then the `Progress...` functions are fine, although not too much different from `ShowProgres[...]`.

The indeterminate progress bar with elapsed time is hopefully a little bit useful in the generic case where it can be difficult to know ahead of time how long a calculation will take.  (Technically, there are times when it's unknown ahead of time whether something will finish at all.)

Comment: A guy earlier said something about the GUIkit(wich I already checked but could not get it to work) but I think he deleted it.

The problem I find with using commands as Monitor and the ProgressIndicator is that they only work for dynamic looping variables (if not, I don't know how that works).

What I am trying to get is something like an "add on", a progress bar that I can just fix into the Mathematica core that will pop on on every notebook I create, so that whenever I start a computation it automatically shows up without me needing to call it every single time. Is this even possible? Thanks

Comment: @EliyahUribe As I said earlier, if you have additional requirements, you should include all of it in your question before posting it. To answer your question, if you don't have a variable/estimate of how long each step/morsel-of-instructions-fed-to-the-kernel takes, then there is no way to know how it is progressing. It is highly unlikely that you'll find something that works like a blackbox for any computation. For instance, how should the progress bar behave in this case: `(Label["a"];Goto["a"];1+1)`

Comment: @R.M I see. Well that's sad to hear, but I was kind of expecting it anyway...I guess I'll just have to indefinitely wait for Mathematica to compute things (like MatrixExp[] in most of the uses I give it, it takes really long).

So, what does the package in the liknk I provided do then? And the progress bar created with the GUIKit package example?

Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: @EliyahUribe From a quick glance, the package you linked to provides a progress functionality (similar to what Brett outlined above) for some common Mathematica functions, all of which either take an iterator or operate on lists. For example, it adds the functionality to `Do`, `Map`, `Nest`, `For`, `Fold`, etc... this, plus some more eye candy (or not) like a window that looks and feels like MS Excel, etc. The GUIKit example allows you to create a widget that looks and behaves like a native OS application.

Comment: @R.M Thank you, this has really enlightened me. Now I'll go and try and find out how to use the GUIKit example.

Comment: @EliyahUribe You're welcome. If Brett's answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking the check mark/tick mark next to the answer.

Comment: @R.M Actually, your I found your comments more helpful :P

Comment: @EliyahUribe If `MatrixExp` takes a long time, then make sure you're not passing it symbolic or exact matrices (since then it tries to do things exactly)

Comment: @Brett ProgressIndicator needs a frontend available. I've added below a solution so that the code can execute when no frontend is available like in Unit tests.

Comment: @Brett I would like to suggest the following extension of your code: `ShowProgress[Table[e_, rg1_,rg2_]] :=          ShowProgress[Table[Table[e,rg2], rg1]]; ShowProgress[Table[e_, rg1_,rg2_,rg3_]] :=ShowProgress[Table[Table[e,rg2,rg3], rg1]]`

Comment: @Brett may be I should have said I would like to ... your extremely useful function that I use all the time ;-)

Comment: @Brett Champion Is it possible to change the code from the beginning of your answer for `ParallelTable`? Just changing `Table` to `ParallelTable` doesn't work.

Comment: @Andrew I think for `ParallelTable` you'd want to do something different, since the fact that you're processing a particular value of `i` doesn't tell you as much because you won't have necessarily completed the calculations for lower values of `i` yet.

Answer (score 17):

You can easily create your own version of a progress bar, and set it up with extras, like a scalebar:

```
progressBar[Dynamic[x_]] := DynamicModule[{texture},
   texture = 
    Table[ColorData["Rainbow", t] /. RGBColor -> List, {t, 0, 1, 
      1/100}];
   Graphics[{
     Texture@texture, 
     Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0}, {0}, {1}, {1}}],
     GrayLevel@.8, Dynamic@Polygon[{{0, x}, {1, x}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]
     },
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0,
    ImagePadding -> {{18, 18}, {5, 5}}, ImageSize -> {70, 300}, 
    AspectRatio -> 10,
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{True, All}, {None, None}}
    ]];
```

Let's test the indicator:

```
x = 0;
progressBar[Dynamic[x]]
Do[
 Pause[.01];(* simulate long calculation *)
 x = x + 0.01,
{100}];
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A slight improvement I've needed based on Brett's initial answer.

The progress bar makes Unit tests in Wolfram Workbench fail as no frontend is available.

Here's a safe version of his code for this problem. Maybe could this issue be corrected in future versions ?

```
SetAttributes[safeMonitor,HoldAll];
safeMonitor[index_,startIndex_,endIndex_,label_,code_] /; $Notebooks :=
    Monitor[
        code
        ,
        Row[{ProgressIndicator[index, {startIndex, endIndex}], index},label]
    ];

safeMonitor[index_,startIndex_,endIndex_,label_,code_] := code;

(*example*)
safeMonitor[i, 1, 100, "Prime", Table[Pause[0.1]; Prime[i], {i, 100}]]
```