# Recovering intermediate results from a Table after an interruption

Tags: evaluation, interruption, result-accumulation

I am interested in knowing if it is possible to recover intermediate results from a `Table` after an interruption.

Let us say I want to produce a really useful table

```
tt = Table[Pause[0.1*i]; i, {i, 50}]
```

and since *Mathematica* takes too long to evaluate it, I get impatient.

Is it possible to interrupt the calculation and recover what it has already calculated? I am guessing the answer is no, but would like to be proven wrong.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/313/how-to-collect-result-continuously-interruptible-calculation-when-running-para/). See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470625/mathematica-table-function/)

Comment: Indeed; sorry about that. The short answer is "it can't be done if it has not been planed" then?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Not an exact duplicate of the first question you mention. That deals with parallel calcluations in which side effects don't work. However the poster answers this question in the statement of his.

Comment: @chris Looks like that.

Comment: Retagged, please feel free to suggest better tags.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since I was corrected and this is indeed not an exact duplicate of the parallel computations question, I will reproduce here [my implementation of abortable table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470625/mathematica-table-function/6471024#6471024), to have it here on SE:

```
ClearAll[abortableTable];
SetAttributes[abortableTable, HoldAll];
abortableTable[expr_, iter : {_Symbol, __} ..] :=
  Module[{indices, indexedRes, sowTag, depth =  Length[Hold[iter]] - 1},
   Hold[iter] /. {sym_Symbol, __} :> sym /. Hold[syms__] :> (indices := {syms});
   indexedRes =  Replace[#, {x_} :> x] &@ Last@Reap[
      CheckAbort[Do[Sow[{expr, indices}, sowTag], iter], Null],sowTag];
   AbortProtect[
      SplitBy[indexedRes, Array[Function[x, #[[2, x]] &], {depth}]][[##,1]] & @@ 
      Table[All, {depth + 1}]
   ]];
```

the usage is

```
tt=abortableTable[Pause[0.1*i];i,{i,50}]

(*  {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} *)
```

(I aborted the computation after some time). Generally, `abortableTable` accepts the same iterator syntax as `Table`, and can work with multiple dimensions. The details on how this works can be found in the linked discussion.

**EDIT**

Per request, a simple abortable `Map` (which only maps on the first level):

```
abortableMap[f_, expr_] :=
 Module[{sowTag},
   Head[expr] @@ If[# === {}, #, First@#] &[
    Last[Reap[
       CheckAbort[Do[Sow[f[part], sowTag], {part, List @@ expr}],Null]]]]]
```

The usage is, for example:

```
abortableMap[(Pause[0.1*#];f[#])&,Range[10]]

(*  {f[1],f[2],f[3]}  *)
```

(again, I aborted manually soon after it started to compute).

Comment: Just a naive question: why is this not the default then?

Comment: @Chris I think it should not be, because this abortable table has more complex behavior than `Table`, and this complexity probably can not be justified in most cases, from the langauge design viewpoint. For one thing, it does not produce deterministic results, because the results depend on when you abort the computation. There are other reasons as well.

Comment: An interesting bit of code, and somewhat different than the original you referenced. It's like an onion, the more you peal back, the more there is, +1.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks :) It is at the bottom of that post, I added it a little later and it probably went largely unnoticed.

Comment: You're right it did. I didn't bother reading past the examples. :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin would it be possible to transpose your code to a abordableMap?

Comment: @chris It should be possible in principle, but `Map` is tougher since you can `Map` on various deeper levels of some irregular expression. Do you intend to use `Map` on a default (first) level, or do you ask about Map with general level spesifications?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin first level would be great.

Comment: @chris Please see my edit.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin would you happen to know why your `abortableTable` seem to partially conflict with the ShowProgress function http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5978/how-to-create-a-progress-bar/5980#5980  as exemplified by `abortableTable[Pause[0.2]; i, {i, 16}] // ShowProgress`

Comment: @chris Yes, I would. You should have inspected an implementation of `ShowPorgress` more closely, which would have revealed to you that `ShowProgress` has special cases targeteed specifically at `Table`. Since `abortableTable` is a different head, it is serviced by a fall-back definition, hence the difference. Replacing everywhere in `ShowPorgress` `Table` with `abortableTable` (or adding new such definitions for `abortableTable` to `ShowProgress`) would remove the discrepancy.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Indeed I should have. Sorry.

Comment: @chris No problem at all. I just meant to say that it pays off to not consider functions as black boxes in cases when their behavior is unclear, particularly when their implementations are somehow available - this way, you have to memorize much less.

Answer (score 9):

You could use side effects instead, thus writing

```
tt = ConstantArray[{}, 50];
Table[Pause[0.1*i]; tt[[i]] = i, {i, 50}]
```

If you interrupt you will find tt partially filled, and you can then finish the rest of an aborted calculation, by letting i take on the values corresponding to the unfilled places:

```
Table[Pause[0.1*i]; tt[[i]] = i, {i, Flatten[Position[tt, {}]]}]
```

Note however that since it relies on side effects, it will for example not work if you `Parallelize[]` it.

Comment: This is clever! +1

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure there must be more elegant solutions than this, but if each step takes significant time, then saving the intermediate results to disk ( or better still a RAM disk or solid state disk ) shouldn't be too much of an overhead.

The benefit here is this is partially resistant to some forms of system lockup or crash.

I've used `Nest` but no reason this couldn't be done with `Table` as well.

```
NestWhileList[
 With[{res = #[[2]][Last@#]}, #[[2]] >> 
    "int_res_" <> ToString[Last@#]; {Append[First@#, res], #[[2]], 
    Last@# - 1}] &, {{}, Sin, 10}, Positive@Last@# & ]
```

In this example `Sin` represents a placeholder which can be exchanged for your function of  choice.

Reflection suggests that extending this to allow restarting might be a wothwhile exercise.

**Update**

**Kernel Crash Resilient Function Application**

Here is a naive, but hopefully useful, stateful solution to applying a time expensive function to a set of parameters or integers that is robust to interrupts and kernel crashes and is similar in spirit to `Map` or `Table`.

The approach is to maintain an externally stored state vector of the progression through the computation. The state vector collects the list of results and holds the unevaluated parameters and applied function.

A history option can be used to store the state for each step, allowing computation to be restarted from anywhere in the sequence.

Support is provided for named execution threads.

*Basic usage*

```
AirBag[Block[{}, Pause[#]; Print@#; #] &, {1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 2}]
```

> 1
>
> 3
>
> Out[335]=$Aborted

```
AirBag[]
```

> 5
>
> 7
>
> 5
>
> 3
>
> 2
>
> Out[336]={1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 2}

*Named execution threads*

```
AirBag[Composition[#^2 &, Plus], {{2, 3}, {3, 3}, {1, 4}, {5, 7}, {6, 7}}, 
       History -> True, FileSpec -> "./air_bag_composite."]
```

> {25, 36, 25, 144, 169}

Restart the named execution thread from an arbitrary step:

```
AirBag["./air_bag_composite.3"]
```

> {25, 36, 25, 144, 169}

```
Clear@AirBag;
Options@AirBag = {FileSpec -> "./air_bag_int_res.", History -> False};

(* Process a state vector -> {results list, function, parameter list, \
iteration counter }   *)

AirBag[state_List, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 NestWhile[
  With[{res = #[[2]][Sequence @@ (First@#[[3]])]}, {Append[First@#, 
       res], #[[2]], Rest@#[[3]], Last@#} >> 
     OptionValue@FileSpec <> 
      If[OptionValue@History, ToString[Last@#], "1"]; {Append[First@#,
       res], #[[2]], Rest@#[[3]], Last@# + 1}] &, state, 
  Length@#[[3]] > 0 &]//First

(* Apply function to the integers 1 to iterations *)

AirBag[function_, iterations_Integer, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 AirBag[function, Range@iterations, opts]

(* Apply function to a list of parameter values *)

AirBag[function_, parameters_List, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 AirBag[{{}, function, parameters, 0}, opts]

(* Restart from a saved AirBag state *)

AirBag[fileName_String, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 If[FileExistsQ@fileName, 
  With[{state = Get@fileName}, AirBag[state, opts]]]

AirBag[OptionsPattern[]] := AirBag[OptionValue@FileSpec <> "1"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this may help you.

```
c = Dynamic@a
a = {};
tt = Table[AppendTo[a, {i, Pause[0.1*i]}]; i, {i, 8}]
```

Here, most code has to do with "automatic" abortion

```
kill = 0;
t = CreateScheduledTask[kill = 1];
StartScheduledTask[t];
c = Dynamic@a
a = {};
tt = Table[If[kill == 1, Abort[], AppendTo[a, {i, Pause[0.1*i]}]];  i, {i, 8}]
RemoveScheduledTask[t];
```