# Is there a Break[] equivalent for short-circuiting in Table?

Tags: programming, list-manipulation

I am running *Mathematica* 7.  The following is admittedly a silly example, but suppose that I have a list `list` whose entries are either `True` or `False`.  Suppose that I have some function `truthFun[]` which evaluates randomly to either `True` or `False`.  I would like to call `truthFun[]` and print `False` until `truthFun[]` evaluates to `True` for the first time.

One way to do this is using a `For` loop.  We can exit the loop "early" using `Break[]`.  (As the documentation states, `Break[]` exits the nearest enclosing `Do`, `For`, or `While` loop.)  For example, the following works:

```
truthFun[] := RandomChoice[{True, False}]

For[i = 1, i <= 10^8, i++,
   If[truthFun[] === False, Print[False], Break[]]];
Print["Finished"]
```

> False
>
> False
>
> Finished

However, it is often recommended that *Mathematica* users avoid using loops (which are relatively slow in *Mathematica*, I think).  Is it possible to accomplish the above using `Table`, which is probably faster?

I tried the following, but unfortunately it appears that `Break[]` does not work with `Table`:

```
truthFun[] := RandomChoice[{True, False}]

Table[If[truthFun[] === False, Print[False], Break[]], {i, 1, 10^8}];
```

> False
>
> False
>
> False
>
> Hold[Break[]]

Also, *Mathematica* gives me this error message:

> Break::nofwd: No enclosing `For`, `While`, or `Do` found for `Break[]`.

Is there an analogue to `Break` in `Table`?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: This would work: `Map[Print, First@Split@list]`

Comment: If you want to keep the results accumulated by `Table` so far, have a look at my implementation of abortable table [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7566/recovering-intermediate-results-from-a-table-after-an-interruption/7571#7571). It can be easily modified to work with `Break` or any other custom form of interruption, rather than `Abort[]`.

Comment: Could use `Scan` to go over the table, and `Return` or `Throw` to exit on condition. If the latter, enclose the Scan in a `Catch`.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the Accept.  By the way, I did not state it explicitly in my answer but you can use `Return[Null, Table]` or the equivalent `Return[,Table]` to get behavior similar to `Break` without the syntax error highlighting.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [lightly-documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/Break/nofunc.html) second argument of `Return` works:

```
Table[
 If[i < 3, Print@i, Return["Exit", Table]],
 {i, 100}
]
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> ```
> "Exit"
> ```

Other examples of use: [(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6757/121), [(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/121)

Additional information:
[What can I use as the second argument to Return in my own functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6815/121)

---

`Break` *also* accepts a second argument but at least on my system the syntax highlighting is ugly:

```
Table[
 If[i < 3, Print@i, Break[Null, Table]],
 {i, 100}
]
```

> 1
>
> 2

---

Somewhat more standard but IMHO less convenient is `Throw` and `Catch`:

```
Table[
 If[i < 3, Print@i, Throw["Exit", "tableBreak"]],
 {i, 100}
] ~Catch~ "tableBreak"
```

Comment: +1 since it answers the question, but I wouldn't do it that way. Except maybe in compiled functions - I wonder if that second arg works with `Compile`...

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't use it in compiled functions either. Then `For` and `While` seems fine.

Comment: @Jens Thanks.  I cannot always write a-guide-to-a-better-way answers (though I try) and sometimes the direct answer is more interesting to me.

Comment: +1 I agree. The particular example in the question might have better solutions, but the Q&A in general is very interesting.

Comment: @Jens `Return` is very dangerous in compiled functions. If you in-line a compiled function with `Return` into another compiled function, the first `Return` will exit both. I can find an example if you like...

Comment: @Ajasja Thanks -- I've never tried it, but I believe you. It's one of those answers that are interesting but could lead newbies to commit horrible crimes...

Comment: @Ajasja Very good point! I too was bitten by this several times in the past.

Comment: What if you wanted to interrupt `Table`, let's say at step `2`, but have it return what it would have had returned if it had stopped at 2? I mean, `Table[If[i < 3, i, Return["Exit", Table]], {i, 100}]` does not return the same as `Table[i, {i, 2}]`. What if I wanted `Table[If[i<3, i, ......], {i, 100}]` to return `{1, 2}`?

Comment: @anderstood `Table` does not keep partial results so you would need to accumulate those manually, with e.g. `Reap` and `Sow` or a similar mechanism.  See: [(313)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/313/121) and [(7566)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7566/121). Consider also using "block based" methods e.g. in my answer to [(21584)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21584/121).

Answer (score 3):

**Clarification: this answer refers to the first the first version of the question, before its entire premise was changed.**

So what you're trying to do is take an *existing* list and then go through its elements until a stopping criterion is reached. But since you already have the list

```
list={False,False,False,True,False,False};
```

it's not necessary to construct another `Table`, just as it's not necessary to use `For` and `Do`. Instead, use a function that can select the desired elements of your list according to a criterion you specify. In your case a simple approach is to use [`Split`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Split.html) because it creates lists of "runs" (i.e., contiguous stretches in your input), based on a criterion that specifies what makes the elements of a run equivalent.

Your simple example doesn't even need any `test` argument for the criterion:

```
First@Split@list
```

> `{False, False, False}`

The run stops when the first element is reached that's just different from the others.

Then you want to `Print` the results (actually, I think the above list is what you'd usually be looking for). If that's required, then you can do it now, after having collected the elements above:

```
Map[Print, %]
```

> `False`
>
> `False`
>
> `False`

**Edit**

In response to the edited question, one could first identify the position of the first element that satisfies the `truthFunction`, and then extract the part of the list up to that position:

```
truthFunction[x_] := TrueQ[x]
Most[
 list[[1 ;; First@First[Position[list, _?truthFunction, 1, 1]]
   ]
  ]]

(* ==> {False, False, False} *)
```

Here I decided to use `Position` with the fourth argument that says to look for the *first occurrence*. Since `Position` requires a search *pattern*, the `truthFunction` has to be preceded by  `_?` or `PatternTest`.

Comment: Thanks for your time.  Sorry for being silly.  I was trying to make a simple working example, but I failed to include a test function.  I have revised my question to reflect this.  I would like to evaluate `truthFun[]` as few times as possible.  I am really sorry take up your time.