# How to force Return[] to return from an arbitrary point (like in C++)?

Tags: programming, return-value

I need to test some complicated conditions to calculate a Return value.  But MMa doesn't let you Return[] from anywhere the way C++ does.  The structure of my Module is similar to this:

```
foo[x_] := Module[{},
 Do[
  If[x == (n^2), Return[0]];
  If[x == (n^4), Return[1]],
  {n, 1, 5}];
 Return[2]];
```

If Return[] actually Return'd, foo[4] would return 0, but instead it returns 2.

Is there a way to do a return from an arbitrary place in the code?

I know that effete programmers will dislike my program structure, but I'm asking how to force the Return[], not how to restructure the program.

Comment: See the doc page of Return under Possible Issues.  Due to how expressions are evaluated, "function call boundaries" are not as clear as in C++.

Comment: Related: [(29353)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29353/121), [(6815)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6815/121), [(18519)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18519/121), [(58059)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58059/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes, a well traveled topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `Return` only exits from the inner most construct. So, even though `foo[4]` hits the `True` clause in the first `If` statement, that only exits `Do`. Instead of using `Return`, use `Throw`/`Catch`, e.g.

```
bar[x_] := Module[{$myTag},
     Catch[
      Do[ 
       If[x == (n^2), Throw[0, $myTag]];
   If[x == (n^4), Throw[1, $myTag]]
       ,
       {n, 1, 5}
      ];
      Throw[2, $myTag]
  ,
  $myTag
 ]
];
```

Note, I use `$myTag` to insulate `Catch` against other throws. Then,

```
bar /@ {1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 16}
(* {0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

If your [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) were not inert you could use the second parameter of `Return` as follows:

```
foo[x_] :=
 Module[{n},
   Do[
    If[x == (n^2), Return[0, Module]];
    If[x == (n^4), Return[1, Module]],
    {n, 1, 5}
   ];
   Return[2]
 ]

foo[4]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Alternatively you could `Return` to [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html) if you eliminate it from within the `Do` loop:

```
foo[x_] :=
  (
   Do[
    {If[x == (n^2), Return[0, CompoundExpression]],
     If[x == (n^4), Return[1, CompoundExpression]]},
    {n, 1, 5}
   ];
   Return[2]
  )

foo[4]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

For a more complete explanation see:

- [What can I use as the second argument to Return in my own functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6815/121)

Comment: That's why `Return[0, Module]` didn't work when I tried it. +1

Comment: @rcollyer I'll admit it threw me at first too but I avoid null `Module` constructs like the plague so I hadn't come across it before.

Comment: I see them occasionally, mostly on here, though, as most feel the need to put some sort of scoping construct around code when simple parentheses will do.

Comment: What does "inert" mean in this context?

Comment: @Jerry I meant that `Module[{}, body]` is simply `body` (in nearly all circumstances) therefore `Module` is inert as in "having no inherent power of action, motion, or resistance."

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Serious question. Is there some deep design logic behind the way Return[] is designed to work in MMa that I'm not sophisticated enough to see, or are there some genuinely stooopid design elements in MMa?  The solutions above worked, but they seem like elaborate contortions to accomplish something Return[] should have been designed to do in the first place.  Am I just not seeing the hidden beauty?

Comment: @Jerry I assume you are speaking of the need to bluntly specify `Module` or `CompoundExpression` for it to work right?  As I see it that is a consequence of the way *Mathematica* evaluates definitions and the need for disambiguation.  It is not apparent to *Mathematica* that you want `Return` to apply to your user-defined `foo` and not e.g. `Do`, and even if it were `Return[0, foo]` *does not work* as Rojo explains in the linked Q&A.  Return as implemented has a few [special uses](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58089/121) that make it important, (continued)

Comment: @Jerry however, I suppose a *different* Return could also be useful.  Perhaps we can even implement one ourselves?  Would you describe the exact behavior that you would like to see from Return?  Would it always be used with `Set` or `SetDelayed` (DownValues) definitions for example?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I suspect that a response you'd find useful is a bit beyond my MMa sophistication. I couldn't make sense of rcollyer's Answer about tags at all. I got your code suggestion to Return stuff the way I wanted it to, but I still didn't understand your clarification about inert Modules or why my Module was inert or what the CompoundExpression thing did. I asked my Aug 11 question in the Comment above because there's SO much in MMa's design that seems to senseless and needlessly complicated to me that I wonder if there's some overarching method to WR's madness that I'm just not seeing..