# Create a table with inline conditions

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to create a table with conditionals inline. For example, I'd like to create a 2 dimensional table like this:

```
Table[{i, j} -> 1, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]
```

Now, I'd like `Table` to generate values *only if* `i != 1`. It should be easy, but I'm lost. I've tried several approaches, like the following, but I don't get what I want in a neat way:

```
Table[If[i != 1, {i, j} -> 1], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]
```

> {{Null, Null, Null}, {{2, 1} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {2, 3} -> 1}, {{3, 1} -> 1, {3, 2} -> 1, {3, 3} -> 1}}

I know, I could delete cases, but there must be a clean and simple way!

Comment: `If[..., bla, Unevalauted@Sequence[]]`

Comment: Seems to be a dupe of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24497).

Comment: @J.M. I actually want to use just Table, so no loops (it is too easy with a loop!) or other commands. Moreover, I'd like (as in the title) to use an inline conditional.

Comment: If you don´t mind the flattening: `Table[If[i != 1, {i, j} -> 1, {}], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}] // Flatten`

Comment: I like this one: `Most@ArrayRules@SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i != 1 -> 1, {3, 3}]`

Comment: I would suggest using `Sow` and `Reap`:  `Reap[Do[If[i != 1, Sow[{i, j} -> 1]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]][[-1, 1]]`

Comment: @belisarius @ YvesKlett I like those!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my mind, it would be better to control the values `i` is allowed take in the second argument to `Table` rather than in the first. For your particular example that means writing the very simple and efficient

```
Table[{i, j} -> 1, {i, 2, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]
```

> {{{2, 1} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {2, 3} -> 1},
> {{3, 1} -> 1, {3, 2} -> 1, {3, 3} -> 1}}

This approach can be quit general. For example

```
Table[{i, j} -> 1, {i, #^2 & /@ Range[5]}, {j, 1, 3}]
```

> {{{1, 1} -> 1, {1, 2} -> 1, {1, 3} -> 1},
> {{4, 1} -> 1, {4, 2} -> 1, {4, 3} -> 1},
> {{9, 1} -> 1, {9, 2} -> 1, {9, 3} -> 1},
> {{16, 1} -> 1, {16, 2} -> 1, {16, 3} -> 1},
> {{25, 1} -> 1}, {25, 2} -> 1, {25, 3} -> 1}}

#### Edit

Adding this to cover the case raised in senseiwa's comment:

> I am not sure how I can use your solution for, say, i != K, given a K > 0.

There are many possibilities. Here is one.

```
With[{k = 4}, Table[{i, j} -> 1, {i, Delete[Range[5], k]}, {j, 1, 3}]]
```

> {{{1, 1} -> 1, {1, 2} -> 1, {1, 3} -> 1},
> {{2, 1} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 1, {2, 3} -> 1},
> {{3, 1} -> 1, {3, 2} -> 1, {3, 3} ->  1},
> {{5, 1} -> 1, {5, 2} -> 1, {5, 3} -> 1}}

Perhaps I should remark that the index specifier for `i` (or any index) in a `Table` expression can be a list specifying the exactly those indexes that `i` should obtain. By creating such a list, either within the `Table` expression (as I have done here) or external to it, it possible to select any subset of an index range.

Comment: I am not sure how I can use your solution for, say, i != K, given a K > 0...