# Stop Computation - Is Exit[] overkill?

Tags: interruption

The following example either finds a factor of the number $n$ or returns a message saying that the number in question is prime (I specifially wrote this to demonstrate my question below).

```
n = 125;
For[i = 2, i <= Sqrt[n], i++,
    If[Mod[n, i] == 0, Print["Factor found: ", i]; Break[];]
 ]
If[i <= Sqrt[n], Exit[];]
Print[n, " is prime."]
...
```

I know I could simply include the last Print statement in the if-condition, but I am specifically looking for a command that makes Mathematica skip the last *Print* statement (and all other statements that might come thereafter...). I tried *Break*, *Abort* and *Interrupt*, but none have the desired effect.

Now the commands *Exit* and *Quit* work, but they terminate the entire Mathematica kernel, which is a bit of an overkill. How could I bypass this issue? I need something like *SkipRemainingCommands*.

Comment: `For` is an overkill. And about Your question, please take a look at `Throw`.

Comment: It is good to avoid `For`, more here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/5478

Comment: *Throw* doesn't seem to be helping me as it produces additional "error" output. I just want Mathematica to stop computing / skip the remaining commands.

Comment: @Kuba this may be a case where `For` is nearly perfect. No output (beyond `Print`) required and minimal use of resources. `Do` would also do in this case.

Comment: Tom, you have to `Catch` the `Throw`, otherwise you get that error.

Comment: @rcollyer I was thinking about `Do` in this case. I have bad experience with `For`, but yes, I'm not a specialist so next time I will be only reffering to question :).

Comment: `Mod[n, i] == 0` is the same as `Divisible[n, i]`. I would prefer `Scan` here over `Do`. You can exit a `Scan` using `Return`. [Related Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24497/4330)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**After comment:**

`Abort` will help You:

```
(Do[
  If[Mod[n, i] == 0, Print["factor found: ", i]; Abort[];]
  , {i, 2, Round@Sqrt@n}];
 Print[n, " is prime."];)
```

> ```
> factor found: 2
> $Aborted
> ```

I understand this behavior of `( )` rather intuitively so I will wait for someone smarter. I assume this is forcing procedures to create `CompoundExpression`, which is also created if You avoid line break between Your loop and last `Print`:

```
Do[ If[Mod[n, i] == 0, Print["factor found: ", i]; Abort[];]
  , {i, 2, Round@Sqrt@n}]; Print[n, " is prime."];
```

> ```
> factor found: 2
> $Aborted
> ```

---

**Before comment:**

It might be good to show/try/learn different way to do this.

**Goto:** This is not elegant and my friend once have told me "do not use Goto in C++", but it works in simple cases:

```
f[n_] := Module[{},
  Do[
   If[Mod[n, i] == 0, Print["factor found: ", i]; Goto["End"]]
   , {i, 2, Round@Sqrt@n}];
  Print[n, " is prime."];
  Label["End"];
  ]
f[15]
```

> ```
> factor found: 3
> ```

**Catch/Throw** mentioned in comments:

```
n = 12;
Catch[
 Do[
  If[Mod[n, i] == 0, Throw@Print["factor found: ", i];]
  , {i, 2, Round@Sqrt@n}];
 Print[n, " is prime."];
 ]
```

> ```
> factor found: 2
> ```

Comment: I really do appreciate the effort, but it is just not what I was looking for. I am aware of Module/Catch/etc. constructions, but I wanted to keep it clean. Hence I was trying to find a simple command that would just stop Mathematica from continuing whatever it was doing.

Comment: @Tom So I have missed the point again :). Please take a look at this edit.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with using `Goto` and `Label` in this situation. We can replace the `For` with `While` by testing the greatest factors.  Of course, any number mod 1 is 0, which gets us out of the  `While`.

```
Block[{n = 115, i = Ceiling[Sqrt[n]]},
  While[0 != Mod[n, --i]];
  If[i != 1, Print["Factor found ", n]; Goto["end"]];
  Print[n, " is prime"];
  (*...other code...*)
  Label["end"];
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Break` to get out of the loop, saving the test result for later use:

```
For[ ....  If[ notprime = (Mod[n, i] == 0) , Break[]] ... ];
If[notprime , Primt["not prime a factor is",i] , Print["Prime" ] ]
```

( I don't even use goto in Fortran code )