# Controlling output of graphics, the role of ";" and code structure/formatting

Tags: graphics, front-end

";" is described under Compound Expression as a delimiter, such that only the output of the last item in the compund expression is given.

Situation:

1/ Print[] produces output whether followed by ";" or not. [Clearly an override is desirable so this makes sense for compound expressions]

2/ When combining graphics using Show[], appending ";" still suppresses output. Since "Show" is as conceptually active as "Print", is there a principle at work here (are there other instances)?

3/ If in procedural code a syntactically complete line is *not* terminated with a ";", the following line is indented... which means Show[] in the middle of several lines of code upsets indentation and code legibility

**Question**: if one has several graphics that one wishes to display without combining them what is the recommended approach, given that multiple Show[] should be separated by ";" but doing so suppresses output.

---

PS There is an incredibly minor-but-irritating-to-the-beginner "quirk" of commenting: semi-colon before comment at the end of code before a closing "]" is marked as a syntax error - is it really? If so, what is the nature of the *error* (it might just be redundant)?

```
Block[{a}, 
 Print[a];(*the ; preceding is magenta, but is it really a syntax error?*)]
```

One is tempted to say the ";" is superflous because the expression is terminated by "]", in which case why is it not still an error when extra line breaks are inserted?

```
Block[{a}, Print[a];
 (*the ; preceding is not magenta, so why is this not a syntax error?*)
 ]
```

Comment: 1) `Print[expr]` is different than `expr`, evaluation will send `expr` via `Print` to `$Output`. 2) If you have `a;`, `b`, `c;` in consecutive lines in the cell then only `b` will be printed. It is not a `CompoundExpression` unless you wrap it with something, e.g: `(a;
 b
  c;)` (*each in new line*) Take a look at first part of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27341/5478) too.

Comment: I think the recommended way is to use `Print[Show[...]];` per line. Unlike `Print`, `Show` has no side effects (at least not since the major changes in how graphics are handled in version 6). The magenta highlighting doesn't really indicate a syntax error, I'd rather consider it an error in the highlighting. If you find that highlighting irritating you could put the `;` after the comment, add another `;` after the comment or explicitly put `Null` after it. As documented `a;b;` is actually `CompoundExpression[a,b,Null]` ...

Comment: and if your `Shows` are `CompoundExpressions` I'd do `(a;
 Return[b, CompoundExpression];
 c;)`, if you really can't put it in a separate line.

Comment: @Kuba, thanks for the expert perspective: the documentation doesn't seem to say anything about a Compound Expression needing to be wrapped and the basic examples suggest otherwise! As for Print to Stdout - I see: I might Print to a file. Per Print documentation though, does that mean that if $Output is not Stdout then it would not "generate a cell styled print"? If so, the documentation could be clearer...

Comment: @AlbertRetey. Hmmm... I see that as Print refers to \$Output, Show refers to \$DisplayFunction... so if Print is pointing to a file, and Show is e.g. a PopupWindow, what happens? Anyway, quirk in the highlighting it is... this beginner did spend rather too much time trying to find a synatx error though!

Comment: `Print` prints to `$Output`, an the usual frontend environment that will create a new output cell (actually a cell with style "Print"). `Print` will also work when used on the command line, there `Print` will really print to "stdout". `DisplayFunction` I consider a leftover from pre-version-6 area: The display of a graphics in a notebook then was a side effect. `DisplayFunction` was a possibility to do interfere with that process, e.g. suppress rendering altogether. Its main value with newer versions probably is when working without a frontend...

Comment: ... instead of `Print[Show[g]];` you could also use `Show[g,DisplayFunction->Print];` but I don't think that is very enlightning...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Again, thanks. At the moment Mma feels like a 10000 page jigsaw puzzle and these insights are slowly helping me organise the pieces. Some apps I have worked with since their inception, and their quirks, foibles and evolutionary legacies are now second nature to me. Mma will eventually become familiar, I expect.