# Problem with Label in a Do loop, "nolabel"

Tags: warning-messages, procedural-programming

Can someone tell me why this code doesn't work and how to fix it ? Thanks.

```
k = 0;
Do[{
  Label[top],
  k = k + 1,
  Print["k = ", k],
  If[k < 4, Goto[top]]},
{10}]
```

> ```
> k = 1
>
> Goto::nolabel: Label top not found. >>
>
> Hold[Goto[top]]
> ```

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27341/5478)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation center:

> `Goto` first scans any compound expression in which it appears directly, then scans compound expressions that enclose this one.

Your `Goto - Label` construction is part of the `List` so Mathematica fails to find the label. Taking this under consideration, the following will work:

```
k = 0;
Do[{
  Label[top]; k = k + 1; Print["k = ", k]; If[k < 4, Goto[top]]
  }, {10}]
```

Comment: "any compound expression" does not read as `CompoundExpression` -- I think this is *not* so clear from the documentation.  On these grounds I am reopening this question.  If the community votes to close it again however I shall not intervene again.