# How can I avoid getting the error message Goto::nolabel in my code?

Tags: syntax, core-language

If anyone could suggest a reason why `Label[begin] ... Goto[begin]` would return  `Hold[Goto[Begin]]`, and (better) how can I avoid this problem, I'd appreciate it. I suspect this is an outmoded control structure for simple programs, but I like it.

I had an earlier version of *Mathematica* and it was fickle. Sometimes adjusting the spacing cured the problem. The newer version is less forgiving, if it is user error.

Edit: a silly example maybe but it gives the error message.

```
p[1] = .9; i = 1; Label[begin];
i++;
p[i] = p[i - 1] + 1;
Print[i];
If[i < 5, Goto[begin], Goto[end]];
Label[end];
```

> ```
> 2
> ```
>
> Goto::nolabel: Label begin not found. >>
>
> ```
> Hold[Goto[begin]]
> ```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Are any messages produced? In particular, ones referencing `$IterationLimit` or `$RecursionLimit`?

Comment: @OleksandrR: no, just Hold[Goto[...]]

Comment: @MichaelE2: Am using 9.0 home edition, same OS

Comment: So, your minimal example produces a message (`Goto::nolabel`) that immediately tells you what the problem is and how to fix it. But you said that your real program produces no message, so are you sure that this is the same problem?

Comment: Does it work if you put `( ... )` around your code?

Comment: @kguler: This is why I like this site. Yes, that works.

Comment: ... or put all your code in a single line?

Comment: @kguler: I tried that, as it has worked in the past. As the program gets longer it's awkward. Can you tell me what causes the problem? Spacing?

Comment: No idea what is causing the problem. Apparently, without the parentheses the parser is seeing multiple compound expressions; and the label `begin` is not in the same compound expression that contains `Goto[label]`.

Comment: [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45153/5478) or even a duplicate. @kguler it is similar to [this topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27341/5478)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the docs for [`Label`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Label.html)

> Label must appear as an explicit element of a `CompoundExpression` object.

So this works:

```
p[1] = .9; i = 1; Label[begin]; i++; p[i] = p[i - 1] + 1; Print[i]; If[i < 5, Goto[begin], Goto[end]]; Label[end];
```

But this doesn't:

```
p[1] = .9; i = 1; Label[begin];
i++;
p[i] = p[i - 1] + 1;
Print[i];
If[i < 5, Goto[begin], Goto[end]];
Label[end];
```

It's because the newlines in an input cell separate the `CompoundExpression` into several input expressions.

Comment: I find kguler's solution easier but this is good to know.

Comment: @daniel Yes, either way, it keeps the input a single `CompoundExpression`.  Parentheses are usually what I use, too, for the same reasons, I suspect.

Comment: Isn't it a [duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45153/5478) that you've closed one time? :P

Comment: @Kuba D'oh.  Memory fault.  +1 to you! :)  I guess nobody remembers, since there are any close votes yet.

Comment: Happens :) +1 for different documentation quote :)

Answer (score 5):

A fix with minimal editing is to introduce parentheses.

```
p[1] = .9; i = 1;
(Label[begin];
 i++;
 p[i] = p[i - 1] + 1;
 Print[i];
 If[i < 5, Goto[begin], Goto[end]];
 Label[end]);
```