# How to make sure Table or Do only runs through specific values?

Tags: list-manipulation

I often need to generate or run through very large numbers of integers (we're talking `{i, 1, 10^9}` and higher) and want to add certain integers to a list, say `list1`.

So far what I've been doing is use the following structure:

```
list1 = {};
Do[If[PrimeQ[i] && Sort[IntegerDigits[i]] == Range[9], AppendTo[list1, i]], {i, 10^9}];
list1
```

(This is an example of a function that adds to `list1` only those values that are prime as well as pandigital from 1 to 9)

Now I realise that this is probably a horribly inefficient way to generate lists. How can I ensure that my `Do` only runs through those functions which fulfil my criteria, e.g. being prime, or being divisible by 14, and so forth, and skips those which it doesn't need to run through - especially when I am running through 1 billion values for `i`? Is this even possible? Won't my function by definition have to run through every value anyway?

Comment: Unless there is a pattern in the search that tells you what numbers to skip, I'm afraid you're going to have to check each number. Obviously there are more efficient ways to do this in *Mathematica*.

Comment: There are about `9! == 362880` pandigital numbers in this range and `PrimePi[10^9] == 50847534` primes. So I'd create a list of pandigital numbers, then `Scan` it with `PrimeQ` and `Sow`/`Reap` the results. Why do you even try for `i<10^8`?

Comment: @Kuba that's a very good point, and would indeed be very useful for this particular problem

Comment: `Reap@Do[If[Sort@IntegerDigits@Prime[i] == Range[9], Sow@Prime[i]], {i,PrimePi[10^8] + 1, PrimePi[10^9]}]`

Answer (score 5):

I interpret your question as a question of how to generically, conditionally, accumulate results, using syntax similar to `Do` or `Table`, rather than how to solve your particular problem most efficiently using some of its specifics.

Here is a generic implementation of a `Table` - like function which accumulates results conditionally:

```
SetAttributes[ctab,HoldAll];
ctab[expr_,test_,iter:({_Symbol,__}..)]:=
    Module[{indices,indexedRes,sowTag,depth=Length[Hold[iter]]-1},            
        Hold[iter]/. {sym_Symbol,__}:>sym/. Hold[syms__]:>(indices:={syms});
        indexedRes=
            (Replace[#1,{x_}:>x]&)[
                Last[
                    Reap[
                        Do[If[test,Sow[{expr,indices},sowTag]],iter],sowTag
                    ]
                ]
            ];
        (SplitBy[indexedRes,Array[Function[x,#1[[2,x]]&],{depth}]][[##1,1]]&)@@
            Table[All,{depth+1}]
    ];
```

It accepts most standard specs for `Table` iterators, including the multi-dimensional case, and is a version of my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24497/instruct-a-table-to-only-evaluate-until-a-condition-is-fulfilled).

Here is how it can be used:

```
ctab[i,PrimeQ[i],{i,100}]

(* {2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97} *)

(pr = ctab[i,PrimeQ[i]&&Sort@IntegerDigits[i]==Range[7], {i,10^7}])//Short//AbsoluteTiming

(* 
   {11.355387,
     {1234657,1245763,1246537,1246573,1247563,1254367,1254637,1256347,
     <<518>>,7564231,7621543,7624531,7625143,7625341,7641253,7642513,7652413}
   }
*)
```

Comment: I am sad/glad my too narrow perspective on this question may have precipitated your wonderfully instructive answer...which I will have to contemplate...it has been a long week...

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks. But I am not at all sure that my interpretation of the question is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Here `Prime /@ Range@PrimePi[10^9]` generates a list of prime numbers, and do is only looping those numbers.

```
list1 = {};
Do[Sort[IntegerList[i]] == Range[9], AppendTo[list1, i]], {i, Prime /@ Range@PrimePi[10^9]}];
list1
```

This seems faster than the `Select` way:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Prime /@ Range@PrimePi[10^6];]
```

> {0.022192, Null}

```
AbsoluteTiming[Select[Range[10^6], PrimeQ];]
```

> {0.260821, Null}

The `IntegerList` function is undefined here so I am not sure what the code is precisely doing. But in case you want to find prime numbers with each digit different (as @ubpdqn points out), you can do

```
Select[FromDigits/@Permutations@Range@9, PrimeQ]
```

> {}

This runs in less than a second but unfortunately nothing found. Permutations@Range@9 can be replaced with another list for broader searches.