# How to improve this dynamic progress bar code

Tags: dynamic, code-review

I created this progress bar to use in my codes:

```
progressBar1[var_,total_]:=Row[{ProgressIndicator[var,{0,total}]," ",  
         Row[{NumberForm[100. var/total,{\[Infinity],2}],"%"}],"% ",var}]
```

But to use it I have to implement like this:

```
Module[{n = 10, i = 0},
    Print[Dynamic@progressBar1[i, n]];
    (i++; Pause[0.1]) & /@ Range[n];
 ]
```

I tried to implement like this, but with no success.

```
progressBar2[var_,total_]:=Print[Dynamic@Row[{ProgressIndicator[var,{0,total}]," ",  
         Row[{NumberForm[100. var/total,{\[Infinity],2}],"%"}],"% ",var}]]

Module[{n=10,i=0},
    progressBar2[i,n];
    (i++;Pause[0.1])&/@Range[n];
]
```

The idea is to change `progressBar2` to make it usable inside Module without necessity to call Dynamic and Print.
I've seen this similar post
[How to create a progress bar?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5978/how-to-create-a-progress-bar)
, but didn't get how to upgrade my code.

Some clue?

Comment: `Module[{n = 10, i = 0},
 Print@ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[x]];
 (i++; Pause[0.1]; x = i/n) & /@ Range[n];]`

Comment: I changed the post to make it clearer. The idea is to change  progressBar2 function, not it implementation. Tks

Comment: The `Dynamic@i` is unavoidable. You need to tell Mma that something is changing ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your definition is `progressBar2` is essentially correct, but it is evaluating its arguments.  This causes the symbol `i` to disappear from your example as evaluation replaces `i` with its value.  The simplest fix is to `SetAttributes[progressBar, HoldFirst]`.

However, we see that almost all Mathematica controls require us to specify explicit `Dynamic` wrappers for dynamic variables.  The purpose of this convention is to help people reading the code spot parameters that are subject to special dynamic processing.  We could follow that convention by making some minor changes to the definition of the progress bar function:

```
progressBar3[dyn:Dynamic[var_], total_] :=
  Print @ Row[
    { ProgressIndicator[dyn, {0, total}]
    , " "
    , Dynamic @ NumberForm[100. var/total, {\[Infinity], 2}]
    , "% "
    , dyn
    }
  ]
```

Following convention, callers of this variant must wrap the variable with `Dynamic`:

```
Module[{n=10, i=0}
, progressBar3[Dynamic[i], n]
; (i++; Pause[0.1])& /@ Range[n]
;
]
```

Incidentally, if you wish for the progress bar to disappear when the computation is complete, replace `Print` in the progress bar function with `PrintTemporary`.