# Improving progress bar code (10 years latter)

Tags: dynamic, monitoring

In the last 10 years ([see this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11661/)) when I want to track the result of a longer calculation, I use the following pattern:

```
SetAttributes[progressBar,HoldFirst]
progressBar[i_,total_]:= Module[{},
    Echo@Dynamic@Row[
        {ProgressIndicator[i,{0,total}]," ",NumberForm[100.i/total,{\[Infinity],2}],"% ",i}
    ]
]
```

so I can monitor a function as follows, using `progressBar`

```
progressExample[data_List]:= Module[{i = 0,len = Length@data},
    progressBar[i,len];
    Scan[(i++;Pause[0.1];f[#])&,data]
]
progressExample[Range[10]]
```

[image]

The problem is that this code crashes for long runs, I think because of the use of Dynamic. Some idea for a better way to do that? Any suggestions for a more modern or native solution?

Comment: Have you reported the crash to the support?

Comment: I think almost any solution will need to use `Dynamic` in some way. So if you are experiencing crashes that you want to prevent, we'll need some kind of example to reproduce them.

Comment: Also, have you seen [`ResourceFunction["MonitorProgress"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MonitorProgress)?

Comment: @LukasLang, this it very interesting. Excellent tip. 

Comment: If the crash is reliably reproducible we'd definitely like to have an example that shows it. (I guess this is paradoxically asking for reliable unreliability.)

Answer (score 9):

If you are willing to explicitly *insert* a call inside your computation loop to a progress updating small function, then you can do this in much simpler way without using Dynamics at all.

It is not a progress indicator, but prints the progress % only. It only uses `PrintTemporary`.  So you have to make this explicit call anywhere in your code you want to update the progress. I would put it at the bottom of the loop for example.

### Video

[image]

### Code

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"PrintAction"}] = {"PrintToNotebook"}
progressBar[currentValue_?NumericQ, maxValue_?NumericQ] := Module[{per},
      NotebookDelete[temp]; 
      per = Row[{NumberForm[100. currentValue/maxValue, {∞, 2}], "% "}];
      temp = PrintTemporary[per];
  ]


progressExample[data_List] := Module[{i = 0, len = Length@data},
      Scan[
            (i++; Pause[0.2];
              progressBar[i, len];
              f[#]) &, data
        ]
   ];

progressExample[Range[60]]
```

### Version that uses PrintTemporary with ProgressIndicator

This version adds the actual bar, but still does not use Dynamics. Only `PrintTemporary`

```
progressBarV2[currentValue_?NumericQ, maxValue_?NumericQ] := Module[{per},
      NotebookDelete[temp]; 
      per = Row[{Spacer[5], NumberForm[100. currentValue/maxValue, {∞, 2}], "%"}];
      temp = PrintTemporary@Row[{ProgressIndicator[currentValue, {0, maxValue}], per}]
  ]
```

So just call the above `V2` instead. This is the result

[image]

Comment: While this doesn't use `Dynamic`, it does perform notebook manipulation (printing and deleting cells). And in my experience, cell creation can be worse for performance than a suitably optimized dynamic expression. But of course, if the `Dynamic` expressions are actually causing the crash, this might help. (Assuming the repeated cell creation doesn't upset the front-end even more)

Answer (score 3):

```
progressBar[i_, high_] := Module[{},
  Row[{
    ProgressIndicator[i, {0, high}],
    Spacer[10], i,
    " (", NumberForm[100. i/high, {\[Infinity], 2}], "%)"
    }]
  ]

progressExample[data_List] := Module[{i = 0, len = Length@data},
  Monitor[
   Scan[(i++; Pause[0.1]; f[#]) &, data],
   progressBar[i, len]
   ]
  ]

progressExample[Range[150]]
```