# Help with Computation-heavy triple integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, physics

I'm Trying to use Mathematica to symbolically integrate a function with respect to x, y, and z.

For some reason, this computation either takes about, 60s and returns the input, or takes many hours and doesn't seem to finish. here is a screenshot of the problem. This is an attempt to integrate the gravitational potential equation over x, y, and z. The constants have been pulled out of the integration in order to try and reduce computation error or time.

[image: integration of gravitational force]

as you can see, at this moment in time, mathematica has been working for over 20,000 seconds (running about 30% on i7 @ 2.8ghz.

I feel like perhaps there is an error in my formatting, because i've run into many problems attempting to perform similar integration. I've used assumptions in past attempts, but they've haven't proved useful.

any suggestions?

Comment: It will likely help to specify `Assumptions->{L>0,W>0,a>0,b>a}` etc (or whatever they should be )

Comment: You can use `Integrate[1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], x, y, z]`, as this does quickly give an answer. Then fill in the bounds manually.

Comment: Can I fill them in manually? How can I fill in the x-bounds if it has then been integrated dy. Should I do this one step at a time? Is there a reason why adding bounds is so hard for Mathematica?

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I'm not sure what to do with that multiple indefinite either - may be a useful answer if you can show the steps..

Comment: The definite form does work with assumptions.. (add z>0 as well ).  The result is such a mess that you may as well just do it numerically though.

Comment: One thing that sometimes "works" is to assign to the positive parameters various mathematica constants. Could in this case do, say,`Integrate[-1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], {z, Catalan, EulerGamma}, {x, 0, 
   Khinchin}, {y, 0, Glaisher}] // AbsoluteTiming`. After which you can substitute with `{Catalan->a, EulerGamma->b, Khinchin->L/2,Glaisher->W/2}`.

Comment: Interesting trick! - it is marginally faster in this case. You need to be wary of conditions on the parameters that might get missed by feeding specific values though.

Comment: What is the `ShowProgress` function code? It very interesting.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Not sure if these give the same code the OP's using, but you might want to take a look at: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5978/how-to-create-a-progress-bar/5980#5980

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since I claimed it worked here is what i did:

```
 xy = Integrate[ -1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] , {x, 0, L/2}, {y, 0, W/2},
    Assumptions -> {L > 0, W > 0 , z > 0, a > 0, b > a}];
 Integrate[ xy , {z, a, b}, 
        Assumptions -> {L > 0, W > 0 , z > 0, a > 0, b > a}]
```

> result a page full of Logs and ArcTans and a few ConditionalExpressions

The full triple integral is taking way longer than the two stage approach for some reason.

Edit.. finally finished ( I also changed the integration order and added b>0)

```
 Integrate[ -1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] , {z, a, b},
       {x, 0, L/2}, {y, 0, W/2},
         Assumptions -> {L > 0, W > 0 , z > 0, a > 0, b > 0 , b > a}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

per Michael's comment after FullSimplify

[image]

Comment: hmm, DO you know where the imaginary component comes from?

Comment: @EverettKnag  From the integration algorithm.  If you do `FullSimplify[expr, {L > 0, W > 0, a > 0, b > 0, b > a}]`, the imaginary `I`s go away.

Answer (score 5):

Using the Rubi integration package for Mathematica (http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/), this takes under three seconds on a late-2014 MacBook Pro, requires no assumptions, and gives a relatively clean result:

```
x1 = Int[-1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], x];
x2 = (x1 /. x -> L/2) - (x1 /. x -> 0);
y1 = Int[x2, y];
y2 = (y1 /. y -> W/2) - (y1 /. y -> 0);
z1 = Int[y2, z];
z2 = (z1 /. z -> b) - (z1 /. z -> a)
```

[Rubi doesn't do definite integrals, which is why I had to add separate statements (x2, y2, and z2) to compute those.]

[image]

AbsoluteTiming for the entire cell was 2.4 s.