# Progress Indicator & sums

Tags: monitoring

Having looked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5978/how-to-create-a-progress-bar), what should I do differently to get the progress indicator working properly?

```
Monitor[Plot[{Pause[0.1]; 
LogIntegral[x] - Sum[2 N[Re[ExpIntegralEi[ZetaZero[n] Log[x]]]], {n, 1, 500}] - Log[2], 
Sum[PrimePi[x^(1/n)]/n, {n, 1, Floor[Log[x]]}]}, 
{x, 2, 1000}], Row[{ProgressIndicator[x, {2, 1000}], x}, " "]]
```

Comment: I'm still exploring but I think the problem is with the speed of `Sum[2 N[Re[ExpIntegralEi[ZetaZero[n] Log[x]]]]`. If you remove that, things work fine.

Comment: This is just an example - what I am most concerned about is that `ProgressIndicator` seems to go through each sum, rather than indicate the progress of the entire calculation.

Comment: `Plot` adaptively evaluates `x` in a non sequential order. Without knowing *a priori* how many evaluations will be needed I see no sensible way to make the progress indicator work

Comment: Your assumption that `Plot` goes from 2 to 1000 in small steps is incorrect.The plot process is recursive, with places that bend too much being refined in later stages.

Comment: ..you can make this work nice, forgoing the adaptive evaluation, by using  `MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 200`

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries, is it possible to make any `Sum` work with `ProgressIndicator`?

Comment: @martin yes, no problem. `Monitor[Sum[Pause[0.1]; x, {x, 1, 100}],  Row[{ProgressIndicator[x, {1, 100}], x}, " "]]`

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries, great - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty way to watch whats going on..

```
 Monitor[list = {{0, 0}};
     Plot[{y = LogIntegral[x] - 
         Sum[2 N[Re[ExpIntegralEi[ZetaZero[n] Log[x]]]], {n, 1, 500}] - Log[2], 
          Sum[PrimePi[x^(1/n)]/n, {n, 1, Floor[Log[x]]}]}, {x, 2, 1000},
           EvaluationMonitor :> AppendTo[list, {x, y}] ],
            ListPlot[list, Epilog -> {PointSize[.05], Red, Point[list[[-1]]]}, 
               PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {0, 200}}]]
```

[image]

What you see is the function globally smooth but locally jagged so the recursion keeps going and going. ( you likely want to set `MaxRecursion` to something reasonable.. )

Comment: ... actually `MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 200` is really what I was after

Comment: Having replaced `ListPlot` with `ListLinePlot`, is there any way to (a) stop the tracing from max back to zero (b) replace each subsequent tracing with the new one?

Comment: ... only achieving (a) would be great ...

Comment: that is just plotting all the points. It gets a bit hairy if you want to show only the points in the current recursion.

Comment: Hmmmm, ok - maybe this will be a separate question at some point then ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the speed of your first sum. I did the following and things worked fine.

```
(zzero[#] = N@ZetaZero[#]) & /@ Range[600];

sum[x_?NumericQ] := Sum[2 Re[ExpIntegralEi[zzero[n] Log[x]]], {n, 1, 500}]

Monitor[Plot[{
   LogIntegral[x] - sum[x] - Log[2], 
   Sum[PrimePi[x^(1/n)]/n, {n, 1, Floor[Log[x]]}]}, {x, 2, 1000}
 ], 
 Row[{ProgressIndicator[x, {2, 1000}], x}, " "]
]
```

[image]

Here's the progress bar in action:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is the issue the OP is referring to. It's not the slowness (the OP added a `Pause` for a purpose), but the fact that the progress indicator starts anew multiple times.

Comment: @Chip Hurst, sorry, should have made this clearer