# Loading screen during evaluation?

Tags: front-end, monitoring

I am just curious,
can I print something while I am working on calculation? Not about how much the evaluation is progressing. Just simple changing image or text. Like loading screen (hourglasses on window or loading donuts on YouTube)

I was thinking something like

```
Monitor[
 Pause[10000],
  "????"
 ]
```

But any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5978/how-to-create-a-progress-bar) and [`ProgressIndicator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProgressIndicator.html)

```
Monitor[Table[Pause[0.1]; Prime[i], {i, 100}], 
 ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Necklace"]]
```

[image]