# Measuring the time remaining until completion for built in functions

Tags: monitoring

All of the functions in [How to create a progress bar?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5978/how-to-create-a-progress-bar), [the `ProgressIndicator` built-in](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProgressIndicator.html) and [Monitoring lengthy computations](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/79076) estimate the completion time for implementation of operations that are indexed.

Is there a way to estimate the completion time for implementation of built-in functions in Mathematica? For instance, to estimate the time remaining for the function `Counts[list]`?

Comment: `Counts[string]` isn't valid - I presume you mean something like `Counts[Characters["abcaa"]]` or `CharacterCounts["abcaa"]`. There is no interface to EvaluationMonitor so I don't think it's possible.

Comment: If it takes a really long time, you might split it up so that each call to `Count` only deals with a part of the list. That way you'll know that you've processed, say, five out of ten parts.